# uiputfile with two-component file extensions

Tags: matlab

I would like to save files from an app as `filename.app.mat`, In this way, it is clear that they are Matlab-files, but I can use `{'*.app.mat', 'App MAT Files}` in `uigetfile` to filter files that are understood by the app.

Now, if I use

```
[f, p] = uiputfile({'*.app.mat', 'App MAT files'})
```

and enter a filename without any extension (let's say, `test`), `f` will be

```
>> f

f =

    'test.mat'
```

Matlab (version tested was R2019a Update 6 on a Linux machine) has only added `.mat`, not (as I expected) `.app.mat`. While it is easy to change `f` to end with `.app.mat`, `uiputfile`'s internal check if the file exists and, if true, the question whether it should be overwritten will not work. A custom check will lead to a different user experience since the file selection dialog will already be closed.

I am looking for a way to make `uiputfile` return `test.app.mat` (in the scenario above).

**Update:**

Due to the comments below, I checked whether the problem exists if I use Windows, too. In the file `uigetputfile_helper.m` (in the `private`-directory next to `uiputfile.m`) one sees that a `matlab.ui.internal.dialog.FileSaveChooser()` is used to choose the file. If I do the following on my linux machine:

```
ufd = matlab.ui.internal.dialog.FileSaveChooser();
ufd.FileFilter = {'*.app.mat', 'App MAT files'};
ufd.show();
```

If I now enter `test` as the filename:

```
>> ufd.FileName

ans =

    'test'
```

while on a windows machine, it will be

```
>> ufd.FileName

ans =

    'test.app.mat'
```

In the linux case, the nested function `fixFileExtensions(filename)` will then add the `.mat`-extension.

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? On R2016a your line works fine. `[f, p]=uiputfile({'*.app.mat','App MAT files'})` will return `f =test.app.mat` if I simply type `test` in the dialog box.

Comment: I mentioned the version at the end: R2019a, Update 6.

Comment: sorry my bad. The line numbers on my version are slightly different but are you sure that the line you indicate is the problem. When it enters the function `fixFileExtensions` the `filename` variable already contains the proper `test.app.mat`. For you I would check what you are getting after the line `filename = ufd.FileName;` (approx line 51 in `uigetputfile_helper.m`), and see if the filename is correct at this point and get trimmed later on, or if the filename is already trimmed at that point.

Comment: With R2019a Update 2 your line also works fine, `f = 'test.app.mat'`. Line 399 in `uigetputfile_helper.m` is the same as what you show.

Comment: I use a linux machine. Maybe that is the difference. In 2018a on Windows, it works, too.

Comment: I have updated the question and included the difference between linux and win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `uiputfile` doesn't create a file, you can write a simple wrapper which will check the extension of the selected file and correct it if it's different than `.app.mat` .

The wrapper can look for example like that:

```
function [f,p,indx] = saveAsAppFile()
    [f,p,indx] = uiputfile({'*.app.mat', 'App MAT files'});
    f = regexprep(f, '(\.app)?(\.mat)?$', '\.app\.mat');
end
```

It's a rather nasty workaround for the issue, but it will get the job done and it should be independent from the used operating system.

---

If you really need the question dialog regarding overwriting already existing file and you can't wait until Mathworks solves the issue for you, you can simply extend the logic of the wrapper. E.g. you can first check which platform your user is using and if it's linux, you can manually check if the file exists. If no - you're good, if yes - pop-up your own dialog asking user if he wants to overwrite the file. In case he doesn't, just display `uiputfile` again.

And yes, of course it will slightly modify the workflow and make it less neat, but again - `uiputfile` doesn't modify the file itself so from the functionality point of view it doesn't really matter if you'll ask the user if he wants to overwrite the file when the file selection dialog is still visible or not. The effect will be exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, but a wrapper does not help. As I said, a wrapper will bypass `uiputfile`'s check if the file already exists. Maybe more important, the true use is within an app derived from `uiw.abstract.SingleSessionApp`, which uses the filename returned by `uiputfile` for several other things before it is delivered to my function which saves the file.

Comment: I wanted to reply here but it became to long, so I extended the answer.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. I filed the problem to Matlab since I believe it's a bug. They will look after it. As a workaround, they suggested to use a wrapper, as you did. However, I'm not really satisfied with it since it really is only a workaround.

Comment: Hopefully they will fix the issue soon!